# Java regex. Keep special characters only when they're surrounded by numbers

Tags: java, regex

I'm making an word frequency program and I'm trying to process text to make it manageable. I'm trying to remove all special characters except $%^*+-=,./<> which are a part of a number. I have virtually no experience with regular expressions and after reading a bunch on it, I tried using the negative lookadead and negative lookaround to get something like

```
   String replace =  "[^a-z0-9\\\\s] | (?<!\\d)[$%^*+\\-=,./<>_] | [$%^*+\\-=,./<>_](?!\\d)";
   text.replaceAll(replace, "");
```

In short I want "they're." to become "theyre" but I want "1223.444" to remain unchanged.

Comment: Do you mean `replaceAll("[$%^*+=,./<>_-](?!(?<=\\d.)\\d)", "")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
text = text.replaceAll(replace, "[\\p{P}\\p{S}&&[^$%^*+=,./<>_-]]|[$%^*+=,./<>_-](?!(?<=\\d.)\\d)", "");
```

Details:

- `[\p{P}\p{S}&&[^$%^*+=,./<>_-]]` - a character class intersection construct that matches any punctuation (`\p{P}`) or symbol (`\p{S}`) except `$`, `%`, `^`, `*`, `+`, `=`, `,`, `.`, `/`, `<`, `>`, `_` and `-`
- `|` - or
- `[$%^*+=,./<>_-](?!(?<=\d.)\d)` - a `$`, `%`, `^`, `*`, `+`, `=`, `,`, `.`, `/`, `<`, `>`, `_` or `-` char that is not immediately followed with a digit which is in its turn not immediately preceded with a digit and any char (`.` is used to match the symbol/punctuation consumed with `[$%^*+=,./<>_-]`).

Comment: Thank you! Just for future reference, the second part will match characters from the list which aren't a part of a number and remove them. What is the logic behind excluding them from the first part?

Comment: @I.B. It is explained: `[\p{P}\p{S}&&[^$%^*+=,./<>_-]]` is an example of a [character class intersection](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html). `[\p{P}\p{S}]` matches all symbols and punctuation. `&&[^$%^*+=,./<>_-]` creates an exception.